# Structure of canvas of p5.js library in html code

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, p5.js

This is my HTML CODE. In the script tag, I have defined the canvas width and height but in js or on my chrome page there is no change in the width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="../p5.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script text="text/javascript" src="AntSmasher.js"></script> -->

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1/lib/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/planck@latest/dist/planck.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://p5play.org/v3/p5.play.js"></script>

  <script text="text/javascript" src="Insect.js"></script>
  

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">
  <div id="AS"></div>
  <script text="text/javascript" src="AntSmasher.js">
    document.getElementById("AS").style.width=Canvas.width ;
      document.getElementById("AS").style.height=Canvas.height ;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code where the function of the canvas is defined

```
canvas{
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  aspect-ratio: 9/16;
}
.AS{
  height : 100vh;
  aspect-ratio: 9/16;
}
```

I tried the getElementById method to define the width of js in HTML to make the width and height screen adjustable but couldn't get results as the canvas height and width are not changing. the canvas dimensions in js are 1080x1920.